# Supertype and subtype relationships

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship

**Entity Types**

[image]

Workstation -> Supertype 
Desktop, Laptop -> Subtypes

Desktop and Laptop share the PK with the Workstation Entity Supertype

**Relationships**

Site – Person -> 1:n 
Workstation – Desktop -> 1:1 
Workstation – Laptop -> 1:1

**Relationships to be modeled**

One person has assigned zero or one desktop 
One desktop is assigned to zero or one person 
One person has assigned zero or one laptop 
One laptop is assigned to zero or one person 
One site has deployed zero, one or more desktops 
One desktop is deployed at one site

**Q:** Is my thinking correct that Person and Site relationships should be modelled with the subtypes i.e. Desktop and Laptop rather than the supertype?

For example, a laptop is not deployed to a particular site, so creating a relationship between the supertype and a location doesn't make sense.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is my thinking correct that Person and Site relationships should be
>   modelled with the subtypes i.e. Desktop and Laptop rather than the
>   supertype?

If I understand you correctly, yes.

The issue for computers, for example, is whether the *real* requirement is that one person has assigned zero or one *computer*. If that's the *real* requirement, then you should use the supertype.  If not, you should use the subtypes.

One of the side effects of using the subtypes is that a person might be assigned both a laptop and a desktop.